# I18n strategies for Go with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, localization, internationalization, go

Not necessarily specific to GAE I suppose, but I'm curious as to what people are using to translate or localise their web applications.

My own approach I'm afraid is hopelessly naive, really just a hand-wave at the issue by loading an entity from the datastore for each package based on a locale value recorded in the user's profile. At least this allows translations of a few strings to be provided:

```
package foo

...

type Messages struct {
    Locale string
    ErrorDatastore string
    LoginSuccessful string
    ...
}
```

Store with a string id corresponding to a locale, then load to Gorilla context or similar:

```
const Messages ContextKey = iota

...

k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Messages", "en_US", 0, nil)
m := new(Messages)
if err := datastore.Get(c, k, m); err != nil {
    ...
} else {
    context.Set(r, Messages, m)
}
```

Which is obviously incredibly limited, but at least makes strings available from calling code via context.Get(r, foo.Messages). Can anyone point me at more useful implementations, or suggest a better approach?

Edit (relevant but not completely useful):

- [gettext: a MO file parser](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/6-MtqMAkTus)
- [go-18n](http://godoc.org/github.com/Astaxie/go-i18n)
- [Internationalization plan for Go](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/_dHb28WG68g)
- [Polyglot](https://github.com/lxn/polyglot)

Comment: Regarding suggested edit: I reserve the right to spell "localisation" [the correct way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29). Hey, at least I used 'z' when tagging! ;)

Comment: What sort of functionality do you expect from a "more useful implementation"? For most i18n applications, key-value stores (with perhaps some format codes) should work fine.

Comment: Well, I guess something that allowed translators to do their job more easily. I was curious if there were ports to Go of other popular approaches (gettext etc) that I might have missed. Right now I'm cobbling together a simple module using [chrome.i18n's JSON format](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html), which I'll post as an answer if nothing more complete materialises.

Comment: Googling "go gettext" brings up this - https://github.com/samuel/go-gettext - have you checked that out? In any case, good on you for writing that module, and good luck!

Comment: No, that one's new to me and that's an interesting consequence of using "go gettext" instead of the (unquoted) golang gettext I'd been searching on! I'll investigate and post an answer if it works out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Jonathan Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124630/i18n-strategies-for-go-with-app-engine#comment19739067_14124630) points out [Samuel Stauffer's](http://samuelks.com/) [go-gettext](http://github.com/samuel/go-gettext) which seems to do the trick. Given the directories:

```
~appname/
 |~app/
 | `-app.go
 |+github.com/
 `-app.yaml
```

Start with (assumes *nix):

```
$ cd appname
$ git clone git://github.com/samuel/go-gettext.git github.com/samuel/go-gettext
```

Source preparation cannot use the _("String to be translated") short form, [due to underscore's special characteristics in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293148). You can tell xgettext to look for the camelcase function name "GetText" using the -k flag.

Minimal working example:

```
package app

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/samuel/go-gettext"
)

func init () {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    d, err := gettext.NewDomain("appname", "locale")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed at NewDomain.")
    }

    cat := d.GetCatalog("fr_FR")
    if cat == gettext.NullCatalog {
        log.Fatal("Failed at GetCatalog.")
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, cat.GetText("Yes."))
}
```

Create the template with:

```
$ xgettext -d appname -kGetText -s -o appname.pot app/app.go
```

Note -k, without it there'll be no output as xgettext won't recognise calls to GetText. Edit relevant strings, email etc in appname.pot. Let's assume we're localising for French:

```
$ mkdir -p locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
$ msginit -l fr_FR -o french.po -i appname.pot
```

Edit french.po:

```
# Appname l10n
# Copyright (C) 2013 Wombat Inc
# This file is distributed under the same license as the appname package.
# Wombat <wombat@example.com>, 2013.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: appname v0.1\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-01-13 11:03+1300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-01-13 11:10+1300\n"
"Last-Translator: Rich <rich@example.com>\n"
"Language-Team: French\n"
"Language: fr\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

#: app/app.go:15
msgid "Yes."
msgstr "Oui."
```

Generate the binary (the file that'll actually get deployed with the app):

```
$ msgfmt -c -v -o locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/appname.mo french.po
```

Final directory structure:

```
~appname/
 |~app/
 | `-app.go
 |~github.com/
 | `~samuel/
 |   `~go-gettext/
 |     +locale/
 |     |-catalog.go
 |     |-domain.go
 |     `-mo.go
 |~locale/
 | `~fr_FR/
 |   `LC_MESSAGES/
 |    `-appname.mo 
 `-app.yaml
```

(locale directory under go-gettext holds test data, could be removed for deployment.)

If all goes well, a visit to appname should display "Oui."

Answer (score 4):

[go-i18n](http://nicksnyder.github.io/go-i18n/) is an alternative package with some nice features:

- Implements [CLDR plural rules](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules).
- Uses [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for strings with variables.
- Translation files are simple JSON.

Comment: Is the implementation of go-i18n safe for concurrent use? This is important here because the OP wants to use it in a go web service. I assume every query needs to use a new object instance of go-i18n that is configured by cookies for the language of the user?

Comment: @Frankenstein there is no synchronization inside of go-i18n; however, synchronization should not be necessary. You should load translations into go-i18n during the initialization phase of your webserver; either during init() or before you have started serving http requests. After that, state is only being read so no synchronization is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Gettext is widely adopted as a de facto standard for i18n solutions.

To use .po files directly from your Go project and load all translations in memory for better performance, you can use my package: https://github.com/leonelquinteros/gotext

It's fairly simple and directly to the point.

So, given a default.po file (formatted after GNU gettext: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) located in `/path/to/locales/es_ES/default.po` you can load it using this package and start consuming the translations right away:

```
import "github.com/leonelquinteros/gotext"

func main() {
    // Configure package
    gotext.SetLibrary("/path/to/locales")
    gotext.SetLanguage("es_ES")

    // Translate text from default domain
    println(gotext.Get("Translate this text"))
}
```

If you prefer to have the translations defined in a string for a more "focused" use, you can parse a PO formatted string with a Po object:

```
import "github.com/leonelquinteros/gotext"

func main() {
    // Set PO content
    str := `
msgid "One apple"
msgstr "Una manzana"

msgid "One orange"
msgstr "Una naranja"

msgid "My name is %s"
msgstr "Mi nombre es %s"
`

    // Create Po object
    po := new(Po)
    po.Parse(str)

    // Get a translated string
    println(po.Get("One orange"))

    // Get a translated string using variables inside the translation
    name := "Tom"
    println(po.Get("My name is %s", name))
}
```

As you can see on the last example, it's also possible to use variables inside the translation strings.

While most solutions are pretty much similar, including yours, using a common format as gettext can bring some extra benefits.

Also, your solution doesn't seems to be safe for concurrent use (when consumed from several goroutines). This package handles all that for you. There are also unit tests for the package and contributions are welcome.